# How to get span element into table row (Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium webdriver. Can someone help me how to get the span element in table row

```
<span class="small-info" title="zim.lu@en.com , stins.gib@en.com "> zim.lu@en.com , stin.gib@en.com </span>
```

in below Table

```html
<table class="k-selectable" role="grid" data-role="selectable">
<colgroup>
<tbody role="rowgroup">
<tr class="k-state-selected" role="row" data-uid="39c56242-2108-4b6d-b80f-1e2f266cd02f" aria-selected="true">
<td role="gridcell">
<div class="left-info">
<div id="item193689" class="inbox-info">
<div class="left-inboxInfo">
<h2 class="SubjecthOverflow">
<span class="small-info" title="zim.lu@en.com , stins.gib@en.com "> zim.lu@en.com , stin.gib@en.com </span>
<div id="policydiv193689">
</div>
<div class="right-inboxInfo">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="k-alt" role="row" data-uid="32a122c7-2e7b-4a28-bb77-5fde6679e6ec">
<td role="gridcell">
<div class="left-info">
<div id="item202147" class="inbox-info">
<div class="left-inboxInfo">
<h2 class="SubjecthOverflow">
<span class="small-info" title="kev.kind@en.com , vin.kami@en.com "> ke.kin@en.com , vi.kami@en.com </span>
<div id="policydiv202147">
</div>
<div class="right-inboxInfo">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried this code

```
WebElement table_element = dr.findElement(By.className("k-selectable")); 
List<WebElement>tr_collection=table_element.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='small-info']")); 
System.out.println("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = "+tr_collection.size());
```

Output not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<WebElement>tr_collection=dr.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='small-info']")); 
System.out.println("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = "+tr_collection.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element by using xpath or css selector

Try this below code in your list

dr.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='grid']/colgroup/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div/h2/span"));